# adding input to doc2vec

Tags: neural-network, word2vec

I've recently started using [word2vec](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/189726/rvecs.pdf) and [doc2vec](http://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf) methods. They are amazing!
But I want to play around with them a bit. As I compared the two methods I saw that the difference is that in doc2vec method, there is one extra input to the neural net, docMatrix. I want to add one more input to the neuralNet (which is a trained vector from somewhere else) and get the output vector for the document. Is it easy to do? Can someone help me to understand what exactly going on in word2vec code?
Thanks :)

Comment: were you able to work this out?

Comment: There are several implementations, so you should state which codebase you're working in.